# Enum versus lookup table

Tags: java, ebean

I'm implementing a solution in Java using Ebean and I'm having some issues choosing between using Enums or simply look up tables.

I have a table "Tooth". A tooth can be "Temporary" or "Permanent".

I could create a simple Enum:

```
@EnumMapping(nameValuePairs = "TEMPORARY=T, PERMANENT=P")
public enum DentitionType { TEMPORARY, PERMANENT; }
```

However if I want to do a direct SQL query I have to convert "T" and "P", so a solution would be to use a lookup table as below:

```
@Entity
public class DentitionType {

    @Column(length = 15)
    public String name;

    private static DentitionType permanent;

    public boolean isTemporary() {
        return !this.equals(getPermanent());
    }

    public boolean isPermanent() {
        return this.equals(getPermanent());
    }

    public static DentitionType getPermanent() {
        if (permanent == null) {
            permanent = DentitionType.FIND.byId(2L);
        }

        return permanent;
    }
}
```

This feels kind of hardcoded and for larger tables a lot of isSomething functions are required.

Is there a better solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am in the same boat where I am trying to figure out the best way to specify reference/look-up table. All my look-ups will be from the database so that I can maintain referential integrity. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @dotnetster I've used the lookup table. But I still find hardcoded...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use?

```
public enum DentitionType {
    TEMPORARY('T'), PERMANENT('P');
    private char value;
    private Currency(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static DentitionType Get(final char value){
        for (DentitionType type : DentitionType.values())
        if (type.name == name)
            return type;
        return null;
    }
};
```